# Sending data using HTTP GET request to Ubuntu server in TCP

Tags: networking, server

I am using an industrial modem (Erco & Gener) to send data to a php webpage hosted on an ubuntu server. On the Ubuntu server side, my webpage answer correctly to an http request through URL of the following format:

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80/testercogener.php?id=i&time=t
```

When I check the database on the ubuntu server, in the mysql database tool everything looks ok, I get my new row.

On the modem, I connect to the server using a TCP protocol on the GPRS network.

My sent data is of the form :

```
"GET /testercogener.php?id=%i&t=%t HTTP/1.1\\r\\nHost:xx.xxx.xxx.xxx\\r\\nConnection:close\\r\\n\\r\\n","H"
```

following the recommendations of Erco & Gener for the syntax (double `\\` for `\`). The Host and the port are entered also using another function in the modem.

This is the log received on the serial interface of the Erco & Gener modem:

```
00:12:29  open socket OK (5)
00:12:29  Gprs_Call_State : GPRS_CALL_TCP_CONNECTION_START
00:12:30  Gprs_Call_State : GPRS_CALL_TCP_CONNECTION_IN_PROGRESS
00:12:30  RECV_STATE_INIT from RECV_STATE_CLOSE
00:12:30  RECV_STATE_RECV from RECV_STATE_INIT
00:12:54  close connection
00:12:54  Gprs_Call_State : GPRS_CALL_TCP_DISCONNECT_START
00:12:54  b_close_session:0  b_reopen_socket:1  state_send:0 NO_ERR_SEND  state_recv:6 Operation now in progress (310)
00:12:54  Gprs_Call_State : GPRS_CALL_TCP_DISCONNECT_CLOSE_SESSION
```

Here is my question: **As it looks to be sent correctly (NO_ERR_SEND), is there a way or a tool on ubuntu server to check if the socket was correctly opened on the ubuntu server side and what was received on its side?**

On XAMPP on windows I had a perfect Netstat tool to check all socket opened and closed and an additional beautiful log file of every GET or POST but I have nothing such on ubuntu.

I suppose this is not a problem of access control as I can do the right operation using url on any web browser from any machine.

Comment: If the server runs Apache2, there is a nice access log in `/var/log/apache2/access.log`. Is that what you need?

Comment: @Jos Thanks that is a good tool. I have repetitive IP adress with an error 408 but I have no GET request I suppose this IP adress is the one of my modem because it tries to send every minute the GET REQUEST. I can see the GET request I send using the URL of the web browser. The 408 code looks to be a confused error code. Do you have additionnal method to better understand what is failing behind this?

Comment: The access log lists not only the IP address, the timestamp, and the actual request, but also the user agent. This may  give an indication of where the requests are coming from, if the IP address doesn't narrow it down enough. Also, a 408 error means that the client has initiated a connection to the server, but hasn't actually sent a request within a reasonable time. I don't think the server is confused, perhaps the client.

Comment: @Jos Thanks a lot. One last question, what can I assume from this? As you could guess I am a noob regarding such TCP/HTTP questions but seeing that I can consider my link using GPRS is OK. My client correctly opens a socket with my server? Is that true? Could it be the server that denies the connection. I will investigate more on the client side.

Comment: It's hard to tell where the timed-out connections originate. Is there something in the error.log? You could run a `tcpdump` on the server to see what other traffic runs between server and client. But in any case the server does not deny the connection. The TCP system allows the "three-way handshake" of which the web server is notified, but after that, nothing happens.

Comment: @Jos Ok with these very useful tools (tcpdump, netstat and the different logs), In can confirm there is no anomaly for the connection. My client is connecting with TCP protocol every 2 minutes, changing of port at each connection. On the server side, the connection looks to be granted, but nothing is recieved, up until the the server close the connection (Time Out). The issue looks to come from the client. If you have still some time, one last question : if I succeed in sending data, to close cleanly a connection after sending, my client should send Connection:Close \r\n\r\ at the end of GET?

Comment: The important thing is the empty line at the end. That signals to the server that the request is complete and that the server can begin responding. The `Connection: close` header signals to the server that it can close the connection (at the TCP level). Otherwise the connection will just time out. The Connection header is optional.

Comment: @Jos: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the access log in `/var/log/apache2/access.log`. The access log lists not only the IP address, the timestamp, and the actual request, but also the user agent. This may give an indication of where the requests are coming from, if the IP address doesn't narrow it down enough. Also, a 408 error means that the client has initiated a connection to the server, but hasn't actually sent a request within a reasonable time. It's hard to tell where the timed-out connections originate. If the `error.log` doesn't give any more cues, you could run a `tcpdump` on the server to see what other traffic runs between server and client. In any case the server does not deny the connection. The TCP system allows the "[three-way handshake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment)" of which the web server is notified, but after that, nothing happens.

The client should close the request with an empty line. That signals to the server that the request is complete and that the server can begin responding. The `Connection: close` header signals to the server that it can close the connection (at the TCP level). Otherwise the connection will just time out. The Connection header is optional.